# C# Form shows with size than other what was set

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm setting form size to 0 and show it with code below:

```
Form overlay = new Form();
overlay.Size = new Size(0, 0);
overlay.Show();
```

But when the Form is shown, it's size is 140x39px.
In constructor of overlay I set it size to 0.
What can be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Why do you want a form of size 0?

Comment: What's the point of showing a zero size form?

Comment: Windows imposes minimum sizes for forms depending on the version. [`SystemInformation.MinimumWindowSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.minimumwindowsize.aspx) tells you what the min size is. If you still want to go smaller than that, then you will probably have to resort to drawing the window yourself.

Comment: @vcsjones Well, drawing a form of size 0 on your own is pretty easy at least...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass 0, the assumption is you don't care about the size and default sizes are calculated based on what needs to be displayed.

You can test this using:

```
Form overlay = new Form();
overlay.Size = new Size(100, 100);
overlay.Show();
```

If this size works, passing 0 may be equivalent to automatic.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the MaximumSize and MinimumSize properties on the Form.  You are probably trying to set a size smaller than MinimumSize.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide your form use Hide() method.

Comment: I assumed he tried to hide the form and showed us just an example of the whole issue because what's the point of creating a form with Size(0,0)?

Comment: Exactly, we don't know the point.  He could be trying to hide it, or he could be trying to do any number of other things; we need to know what the actual problem is in order to be able to suggest the appropriate solution.